# Logging always prints basic output, despite never being told to

Tags: python, logging

When I try to log from my script, it always generates basic logging output. There is no configuration for this.

The code is the following:

```
def set_logger():
    res_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='%s.log' % __file__)
    res_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    file_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s]\t{%(filename)s:%(lineno)d}\t%(levelname)s\t- %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
    stdout_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s]\t{%(filename)s:%(lineno)d}\t%(levelname)s\t- %(message)s')
    stdout_handler.setFormatter(stdout_formatter)
    res_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    res_logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
    return res_logger


logger = set_logger()

logger.error("TEST")
```

The output with this setup should be `[2018-04-17 15:50:31,601] {filename.py:60}    ERROR   - TEST` in my stdout and in the filename.py.log file.

However, the actual output is

```
ERROR:__main__:TEST
[2018-04-17 15:57:37,756]   {filename.py:60}    ERROR   - TEST
```

What's even weirder: I can't use "logging.error('test')" to produce basic output, even if I never declare a logger. It just produces nothing. And this ONLY happens to this script. If I copy-paste the same code to a new script, it all works fine. There is no logging configuration being done in the whole script, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42dvW.png)

All of the 9 times "logging" is written are shown in the image. The only time "logger" is used, is when there are logs to produce.

I can't see why its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something *else* is almost certainly configuring logging and adding another handler which outputs to console. For example, if I copy your code to `footest.py` and add an `import logging, sys` at the top and run it using

```
python -c "import footest"
```

I get the output you would expect. But if I insert a line

```
logging.debug('foo')
```

and then run the python command again, I get the extra line. The `logging.debug('foo')` doesn't output anything, as the default level is `WARNING`, but it adds a handler which is used when the `logger.error('TEST')` at the bottom is executed.